# Parse - iOS - Download when Uploaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am making a messaging app, and I want to download a message from parse the moment it is uploaded, like iMessage. Is there any possible way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at sockets. it can help u in making real time messaging.

also, you might be interested in lib for sockets for iOS-app: https://github.com/square/SocketRocket

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use Push Notifications then, to notify the client of the new message, or the need to download new messages.